# File analyzer and sorter

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, disk-analysis, file-search

I need a Windows software which can analyze a folder or a drive and index the files and then categorize them in different categories and I can view and sort scanned files based on different criteria for example based on file type, date, size, etc. and also I want that it let me combine different filters for example *find docx files larger than 3MB and created in May 2016*.

**Being fast in scanning and indexing is one of the important requirements**. Because My data are about 20TB and maybe more and each of my partitions is 3TB and the matter of time in searching is very very Important for me. And also I like it to be free and only for Windows but if there is a very perfect one and not free I'll try.

[WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) is a perfect software which is free and very very fast in scanning and analyzing but it only can analyze folders based on file types and no other criteria can be used.

Comment: How do we know when `etc.` is fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used and liked (in order of personal preference) [UltraSearch](http://www.jam-software.com/ultrasearch/), [Super Finder XT](http://fsl.sytes.net/ssearchxt.html) and [FileSearchEX Trial](http://goffconcepts.com/products/filesearchex/index.html) . All 3 do what you describe and integrate well with Windows.

Comment: Thank you for these recommendations. These are nice but I find that they cannot index the files one time in order to speed up my searches every time I search. I mean the program scan one time and index the results and every search I perform it searches through its own index and not to perform the search from the very very beginning.

Comment: While UltraSearch is indeed index-free, it actually is quite fast. They claim that this is because they work directly on your NTFS partitions' Master File Table (MFT). If you're specifically looking for index-based tools, try [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/faq/) or [Listary](http://www.listary.com/faq). I know someone who uses and likes the latter, but I found the UI clunky.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ffind](http://bvdsw.com/ffind/). Ext edition allows to specify file type, time, size, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Everything from [Voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This reminds me [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/). From their site:

> Are you frustrated by the limitations of Windows Explorer? Directory
>   Opus is a complete replacement for Explorer, with far more power and
>   functionality than any other file manager available today.

Can it analyze folders: No, but it has advanced searching capability

Can it categorize files in different categories: I guess no, you could do this manually

Is searching speed fine: As it is using Windows Explorer

<strike>Does it have free version: Yes</strike>

**EDIT:** I would just use something like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com). I did this search in 10 seconds.

I must say it's paid either.

[image: Total Commander screenshot]

Comment: It has "Free 60 day evaluation!", which not what I understand when I read that it has a "free version". Can you point to a free version? If not, I guess that's another "no" to your list

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot.

Comment: But, is the lite eidtion free?

Comment: It isn't I myself had to buy a license for the light edition.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know Directory Opus was paid.